# Theano reshape – index out ouf bounds

Tags: python, debugging, reshape, theano

I can't seem to get Theano to reshape my tensors as want it to. The reshaping in the code bellow is supposed to keep `keep_dims` dimensions and flatten all remaining ones into a single array.

The code fails with `IndexError: index out of bounds` on the `reshape` line if I run it with a test value. Otherwise, the function seems to compile, but fails upon first real input with `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`.

When I tried using just numpy for an equivalent code, it worked normally. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Or is there any easy way to see the resulting dimensions that are used for the reshaping (`ipdb` does not help since everything is a Theano variable)?

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

theano.config.compute_test_value = 'warn'
theano.config.optimizer = 'None'


class Layer(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = []

    def get_init_weights(self, shape):
        rows, cols = shape
        w_init = np.reshape(np.asarray([rnd.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)
                                        for _ in xrange(rows * cols)]),
                            newshape=(rows, cols))
        return w_init

class Embedding(Layer):

    def __init__(self, name, dict_size, width, init='uniform_005'):
        super(Embedding, self).__init__(name)
        self.width = width
        self.dict_size = dict_size
        e_init = self.get_init_weights((dict_size, width))
        self.e = theano.shared(value=e_init, name=self.name)

    def connect(self, inputs):
        output = self.e[inputs]
        self.inputs.append(inputs)
        self.outputs.append(output)
        return output

class Flatten(Layer):

    def __init__(self, name, keep_dims=1):
        super(Flatten, self).__init__(name)
        self.params = []
        self.keep_dims = keep_dims

    def connect(self, inputs):
        keep_dims = self.keep_dims

        # this line fails
        output = inputs.reshape(inputs.shape[0:keep_dims] +
                                (T.prod(inputs.shape[keep_dims:]),),
                                ndim=(keep_dims + 1))
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = T.itensor3('x')  # batch embedding * embedding size * number of different embeddings
    x.tag.test_value = np.random.randint(0, 50, (5, 20, 3)).astype('int32')

    emb_layer = Embedding('e', dict_size=50, width=10)
    y = emb_layer.connect(x)
    flat_layer = Flatten('f')
    y = flat_layer.connect(y)

    func = theano.function([x], y, allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relates to how you're combining the two components of the new shape. The [`reshape` command requires an `lvector` for the new shape](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.reshape).

Since you're using the test values mechanism you can debug this problem by simply printing test value bits and pieces. For example, I used

```
print inputs.shape.tag.test_value
print inputs.shape[0:keep_dims].tag.test_value
print inputs.shape[keep_dims:].tag.test_value
print T.prod(inputs.shape[keep_dims:]).tag.test_value
print (inputs.shape[0:keep_dims] + (T.prod(inputs.shape[keep_dims:]),)).tag.test_value
print T.concatenate([inputs.shape[0:keep_dims], [T.prod(inputs.shape[keep_dims:])]]).tag.test_value
```

This shows a fix to the problem: using `T.concatenate` to combine the `keep_dim`s and the product of the remaining dims.

Comment: Great, thanks! I somehow missed that you can call `.tag.test_value` on shapes as well.

Comment: Just FYI, `x.tag.test_value.shape` and `x.shape.tag.test_value` will give the same result.